# How to build nested array of 1x3 vectors in the n,m posision of 2D matrix in MATLAb?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, vectorization

How to build nested array of 1x3 vectors in the (n,m) posision of 2D matrix in a for loop?

And then how to access the n,m vector ?

Is there a better way than below.

```
  for n =1:2
     for m =1:3
       v = [n,m,n]' % test vector to be stored
       A(3*n-2:3*n,m) = v;% 
      end
  end
n =2; m=3;
v = A(3*n-2:3*n,m); % get vector at n,m position
A
v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ndgrid`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) and some re-arrangement later on with [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) + [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to get the desired output -

```
%// Get the vector v values which are rectangular grid data on a 2D space
[X,Y] = ndgrid(1:n,1:m)

%// Reshape those values and re-arrange into a 2D array as the final output
X1 = reshape(X.',1,[]) %//'
Y1 = reshape(Y.',1,[]) %//'
A = reshape(permute(reshape([X1 ; Y1 ; X1],3,m,[]),[1 3 2]),n*3,[])
```

---

Or you can use [`meshgrid`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) there (thanks to comments by @horchler) for a compact code -

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:n,1:m); 
A = reshape(permute(reshape([X(:).';Y(:).';X(:).'],3,m,[]),[1 3 2]),n*3,[])
```

Comment: Why `ndgrid` instead of `meshgrid` for this? Could you not replace the first three lines with: `[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:n,1:m);` `X1 = X(:).';` `Y1 = Y(:).';`?

Comment: @horchler Thanks for that input! Added those codes!